Need help defining L*u'v' color space in PostScript using ` setcolorspace`
I read the basics about the L*u'v' color space, and I also read the basics about PostScript's setcolorspace, but I'm unable to transform the formulas in a way PostScript wants.
$$
{L^*}(I) = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\left(\frac{116}{12}\right)^3 * \frac{I}{I_N}
& \text{for} \quad \frac{I}{I_N} \le \left(\frac{24}{116}\right)^3 \\
& 116 * \left(\frac{I}{I_N}\right)^\frac{1}{3} - 16 
& \text{for} \quad \frac{I}{I_N} > \left(\frac{24}{116}\right)^3
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
$$
u' = \frac{4 * X}{X + 15 * Y + 3 * Z}
\:,\quad
v' = \frac{9 * Y}{X + 15 * Y + 3 * Z}
$$
The formulas are basically from page 261 of Charles Poynton's Digital Video and HD.
PostScript has CIEXYZ color space built-in, so I would need to convert L*u'v' to XYZ.
The difficult part is that PostScript (as I understand it) only allows each of the components (L*, u', v') to be adjusted using a (non-linear) scaling function and a linear transformation represented by a matrix.
In the PostScript reference manual there is only one example given for the L*a*b* color space, but it doesn't explain the details.
So what I would have to do is invert the formulas given like
$$
X = f(L*, u', v')
\:,\quad
Y = g(L*, u', v')
\:,\quad
Z = h(L*, u', v')
$$
and then implement these functions f, g, and h in a way setcolorspace accepts.
I wrote the conversion from L* to Y like this:
% v^3
/p3 {   % def: v
    dup dup mul mul
} bind def
/threshold 24 116 div p3 def
/factor 116 12 div p3 def

/L*-to-Y {      % def: L*
    dup threshold gt {  % ifelse
        16 add 116 div p3
    }
    {
        100 mul factor div
    } ifelse
} bind def

But I was rather clueless regarding the rest:
% White point D65
/WP_D65_X 0.9505 def
/WP_D65_Y 1.0 def
/WP_D65_Z 1.0890 def

/Luv [
    /CIEBasedABC
    <<
        /RangeABC [0.0 1.0 0.0 0.7 0.0 0.6]
        /DecodeABC [            % decode individual A, B, C
            { L*-to-Y }
            { 4 div }
            { 9 div }
        ]
        /MatrixABC [            % combine (A, B, C) to (L, M, N)
            1 0 0
            0 1 0
            0 0 1
        ]
        /DecodeLMN [            % decode individual L, M, N
            { }
            { }
            { }
        ]
        /WhitePoint [WP_D65_X WP_D65_Y WP_D65_Z]
    >>
] def
Luv setcolorspace

